# Cast object type in a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a `Layer` collection which contains a `Content` object as a property. How do I cast this `Content` to its original object to get its property in LINQ statement?

For example:

```
var item = Layers.FirstOfDefault(x =>(PushPin)x.Content.Description == "xyz");
```

In this case `Content` is of `PushPin` object type and I want to compare its `Description` property to `xyz`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose it with parentheses

```
var item = Layers.FirstOfDefault(x => ((PushPin)x.Content).Description == "xyz");
```

Comment: Having accepted this as the answer, please be mindful of cases where Content is not of type PushPin as the code will throw an exception. Also, if the Content property is ALWAYS of type PushPin then I would recommend changing it's type to PushPin to avoid the boxing operation in the filter.

Answer (score 6):

If Content can be something other than PushPin then you will need something along the lines of

```
var item = Layers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Content is PushPin && ((PushPin)x.Content).Description == "xyz");
```

Comment: In my mind, this is a more complete example as it prevents an exception from occurring due to an improper cast.

Answer (score 1):

If all content objects in Layers are PushPin objects this should be ok for you:

```
var item = Layers.Select(x => x.Content).Cast<PushPin>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Description == "xyz");
```

But this will throw an `InvalidCastException` if there are objects in Layers which cannot be casted to PushPin. If Layers contains different object-types but you only need the PushPins, `OfType` should work:

```
var item = Layers.Select(x => x.Content).OfType<PushPin>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Description == "xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

When `Content` can be something other then `PushPin`

```
var item = Layers.Select(x => x.Content).OfType<PushPin>().FirstOfDefault(c => c.Description == "xyz");
```

or when all `Content` are `PushPin`'s

```
var item = Layers.Select(x => x.Content).Cast<PushPin>().FirstOfDefault(c => c.Description == "xyz");
```

i.e. the first one will filter the `PushPin` types, the second one will cast all Content to `PushPin`.